# Boots correctly but says "No HDMI signal" after finishing kernel boot logs

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, hdmi, video

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (8GB), I have flashed the latest version of Raspbian into a USB flash drive and I boot it from there. I've had no problems so far. Today I restarted it after about 2-3 days. After showing the kernel boot logs, the monitor's "No signal" message appears. I tested multiple monitors but again the same. The kernel boots correctly, so I have access to ssh. I've also tried alternating HDMI settings on config.txt but nothing have worked so far. Thanks in advance for your time.

kernel logs (dmesg) : https://paste.debian.net/hidden/ea8b0ce2/

config.txt : https://paste.debian.net/hidden/2319d387/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with a different HDMI cable and it was fixed. Sorry for interrupting.